# Show more content on click title underneath title

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, click

I need to show the content of post in wordpress. Basically I need to show a div on click, but only the current post. I have the title and the excerpt looping on the page to show all post. I want to show the content of only the current title post clicked. Example below is what I currently have.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.post-id', function() {
 $(myClass, ".post-content").show();
});
```

```html
<div class="post-full">
<h2 class="post-id<?php //echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><div class="close">Close</div></h2>
<div class="post-excerpt"><h3><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h3></div>
<div class="post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly

```
$(document).on('click', '.post-id', function()
{
    var content = $(this).nextAll('.post-content');

    if (content.is(':visible'))
    {
        content.hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.post-content:visible').hide();

        content.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Cool, yes that works, now how to I close all others that are open?

Comment: That doesnt seem to work, I dont know if it matters, but I am using "display: none" on div until clicked then show.

Comment: Awesome that worked, one more I think, now can I also have current show close on click again of title?

Comment: @Anthony check new version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82228/discussion-between-alexander-madyuskin-and-anthony).

Comment: I need to hide another div on click when post-content is shown, then when closed, the div is shown again.